# Debug Assertion Failed error while comparing unicode using isdigit

Tags: c++, string, assert

I have the debug assertion error in the `if statement` when `i = 7`:

```
Expression: c>= -1 && c <= 255
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const char* clearString(std::string str)
{
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (  !isdigit(str[i])
            && str[i] != ',')
        {
            str.erase(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return str.c_str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "688,13 €";

    std::cout << clearString(str);
}
```

I try to delete all characters in the string that are not numbers and ','.

Comment: Your `clearString` causes undefined behavior. Can you change the return type to `std::string`?

Comment: `return str.c_str();` -- Yes, this is broken.

Comment: @Timo, I have tried `std::string` and I have got the same error. The error occurred in the `if` statement when the `i = 7`.

Comment: @Kiseea -- The comments about the return type is to prevent another error from occurring, that error being you not able to get any output.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , I understood, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `std::isdigit`, see the [Notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) as to  why you are getting the assertion.

The fix is to cast to an `unsigned char`:

```
if (!isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]))
```

Second, your function returns the address of a local temporary, thus exhibits undefined behavior.  Return a `std::string` instead.

```
std::string clearString(std::string str)
{
   //…
   return str;
}
```

Third, you could rewrite your function using `std::remove_if` and `std::string::erase`, instead of writing a loop that removes a character at a time.

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::string clearString(std::string str)
{
    auto iter = std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
          [&](char ch) 
         { return !isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)) && ch != ',';});
    str.erase(iter, str.end());
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `isdigit()` works only with chars that their decimal value is between -1 and 255.

The decimal value of the character `€` is `-128` which the function doesn't support.

I would suggest to change the comparison instead of using `isdigit()`, compare the decimal values of the chars.

Change your function to this:

```
const char* clearString(std::string& str)
{
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') && str[i] != ',')
        {
            str.erase(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return str.c_str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little out of topic, about your algorithm.

It would be better if you don't erase every non-digit character, but shift your characters left, skipping all non-digits (except ',') and resize string.

About `isdigit` I would do how 0xBlackMirror suggested, compare to '0' and '9'.

Here is the code:

```cpp
const char* clearString(std::string str)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') || str[i] == ',')
        {
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    str.resize(j);
    return str.c_str();
}
```